# Selecting columns from tables based on max value of another column

Tags: sql, date, join, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables and I want column input from `first_table` and column output from `second_table` based on the latest finished time

first_table:

```
id    input    
--------------
1     America    
2     China      
3     Russia     
2     China      
3     Russia
```

second_table

```
id    output     finished_time
-------------------------------------------------
1     Washington    10/5/2019 10:05:13 PM +00:00
2     Shanghai      10/6/2019 10:05:13 PM +00:00
3     Kazan         10/7/2019 10:05:13 PM +00:00
2     Beijing       10/10/2019 10:05:13 PM +00:00
3     Moscow        10/11/2019 10:05:13 PM +00:00
```

result_table

```
id    input      output  
-----------------------------
1     America    Washington
2     China      Beijing
3     Russia     Moscow
```

I am trying to use this query:

```
SELECT input, second_table.output
FROM first_table
INNER JOIN second_table ON first_table.id = second_table.id 
                        AND Max(finished_time)
```

Comment: Why did you tag this question [java]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery in the `on` clause of the join:

```
select
    f.*,
    s.output
from first_table f
inner join second_table s
    on  s.id = f.id
    and s.finished_time = (
        select max(s1.finished_time)
        from second_table s1
        where s1.id = s.id
    )
```

For performance here, you want an index on `second_table(id, finished_time)`.

This can also be expressed with a `not exists` condition:

```
select
    f.*,
    s.output
from first_table f
inner join second_table s 
    on  s.id = f.id
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from second_table s1
        where s1.id = s.id
        and s1.finished_time > s.finished_time

    )
```

Finally, another option is to use a window function for ranking

```
select id, input, output
from (
    select
        f.*,
        s.output,
        rank() over(partition by s.id order by s.finished_time desc) rn
    from first_table f
    inner join second_table s on s.id = f.id
) x
where rn = 1
```

You can play around with the solutions and pick the one that you understand better, or that performs faster.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with your first query where you are using max function, it took 34 seconds to execure. Your second query where you are using not exists take 47 seconds. Third query where you are using rank took a very long time, so I stopped

Answer (score 1):

You can use a derived table of maximum `finished_time` per country and then join that back to the country and cities tables:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1."input", t2."output"
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, "input"
      FROM first_table) t1
JOIN second_table t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(finished_time) AS max_time
      FROM second_table t2
      GROUP BY id) m ON m.id = t2.id AND m.max_time = t2.finished_time
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Output:

```
ID  input       output
1   America     Washington
2   China       Shanghai
3   Russia      Kazan
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e1735b678baf8a76042cd1ed9248fa72)

Note I've added a `SELECT DISTINCT` to `first_table` as you have duplicated rows in that table which would then result in duplicated rows in the output.

Comment: thanks for your help and time but it did not work, I got this error:
Error 8155: No column name was specified for column 2 of 'm'.

Comment: @Cathy Apologies - I've corrected the query (it should be fairly SQL variety agnostic). I noticed you benchmarked the other answers, if this one works for you I'd be really interested to find out how it compares speed wise.

Comment: Hi @Cathy, thanks for that - I appreciate you taking the time. I wouldn't have expected that query to be that much slower than the others as it only performs the `MAX(finished_time)` query once instead of once per `JOIN`. It might be related to the `SELECT DISTINCT` I did on `first_table` which might not actually be necessary. Anyway, interesting results. thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your effort and time. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If your second_table.finished_time has an associated index this is efficient too

```
SELECT input , second_table.output
FROM first_table
INNER JOIN second_table ON first_table.id= second_table.id
ORDER BY second_table.finished_time DESC
limit 1;
```